# 404 while serving static files via docker nginx

Tags: nginx, docker

I've build a new docker container based on the latest official image.

Everything works fine so far except serving static files via nginx.

I guess it could be an error in the server block file, but this is the configuration which works fine in a non docker environment.

As mentioned in multiple answers I already include the mime-types under location / { ... }. This didn't solved my problem, too.

Here are my configurations:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.11
        ports:
            - "7200:80"
        volumes:
            - "./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
            - "./docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx"
            - ".:/var/www"
    php:
        build: ./docker/php/
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www/html/"
    node:
        image: node:7.5
        volumes_from:
            - php
        working_dir: "/var/www/html/assets/"
    composer:
        image: composer:1.1
        volumes_from:
            - php
        working_dir: "/var/www/html/"
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "7201:80"
        links:
            - mysql
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
```

default.conf (server block for the project)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Block access to .htaccess
    location ~ \.htaccess {
       deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php(?:/.+)?$ {
        rewrite ^(.+.php)(?:/(.+))$ $1?request=$2 break;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /assets/img/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /.well-known { allow all; }
    location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
}
```

Thank you for every answer/suggestion.

Comment: What error you recieve from nginx? Is there any information in nginx logs?

Comment: I get 404 error from nginx. The error.log tells me for a /assets/css/style.css "No such file or directory". The access.log a 404. 

If I place a phpinfo() in /assets/css/info.php there is no problem.

Comment: Can you see that file when you attach to the docker container?